# Run loop inside an object creation

Tags: javascript, loops

I know this completely wrong but I'm stuck.

I have an array of objects.

From this I would like to create 3 objects.

The first object created I need an array that has all the 'uppVal' values in the original objects.

The second object created needs the 'midVal' values and the third object the 'lowval' values

I know this is wrong

```
outputData.push({
    dataNum: []
    for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
      dataNum.push(data[n][key])
    }
  })
```

but I'm trying to get the values while creating the object

```js
var outputData = [];

data = [{
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  },
  {
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  },
  {
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  },
  {
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  },
  {
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  },
  {
    "uppVal": 68,
    "midVal": 34,
    "lowVal": 4,
  }
]

titlesArr = ['uppVal', 'midVal', 'lowVal']

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var counter = 0
  var key = titlesArr[counter]
  outputData.push({
    dataNum: []
    for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
      dataNum.push(data[n][key])
    }
  })
  counter++
}

console.log(outputData);
```

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to switch `data[index][key]` to `outputData[key][index]`:

```js
data = [ { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 },
         { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 },
         { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 },
         { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 },
         { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 },
         { "uppVal": 68, "midVal": 34, "lowVal": 4 } ]
         
outputData = { uppVal: [], midVal: [], lowVal: [] }

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
    outputData.uppVal[i] = data[i].uppVal
    outputData.midVal[i] = data[i].midVal
    outputData.lowVal[i] = data[i].lowVal
}

console.log(outputData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the given data and the array of keys and assing to the result set with the index of the keys.

```js
var data = [{ uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }, { uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }, { uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }, { uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }, { uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }, { uppVal: 68, midVal: 34, lowVal: 4 }],
    result = [[], [], []];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    ['uppVal', 'midVal', 'lowVal'].forEach(function (k, i) {
        result[i].push(o[k]);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```